# Invalid local name: C.UTF-8 even though the collname exist in pg_collation.collname

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, edgedb

As this might have something to do with AWS Lightsail, I've cross posted this question on AWS - [Click Here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=339264)

I'm trying to create a template database using

```sql
CREATE DATABASE __edgedbtpl__  OWNER='edgedb' IS_TEMPLATE = TRUE TEMPLATE='template0' ENCODING='UTF8' LC_COLLATE='C' LC_CTYPE='C.UTF-8';
```

But this fails and gives me the error

```
ERROR:  invalid locale name: "C.UTF-8"
```

I checked if the PostgreSQL server supports the C.UTF-8 locale, using

```
SELECT collname FROM pg_collation WHERE lower(replace(collname, '-', '')) = 'c.utf8' LIMIT 1;
```

which gives me the response

```
 collname 
----------
 C.utf8
(1 row)
```

**Question**

1. How are the `collnames` in `pg_collation` different from `SHOW LC_CTYPE` and `SHOW LC_COLLATE`?
2. `SHOW LC_COLLATE` and `SHOW LC_TYPE` responded with `en_US.UTF-8` and not `C.UTF-8`. So how should I identify if a certain locale is supported?

Answer (score 0):

Collation names are identifiers, not string literals in PostgreSQL. Use double quotes instead of single quotes. Also, case and spelling matter, so use `"C.utf8"`.

Comment: You got the case wrong (`utf` is lower case), and there is no hyphen in the name. See my updated answer.

Comment: The command `locale -a` gives you the list of all supported locales in your system.

Comment: Unlikely. Please show the exact command string.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm connected to a AWS Lightsail postgres instance. Unlike RDS I don't have fine grained access to its features

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Here is the whole command string `CREATE DATABASE __edgedbtpl__  OWNER='edgedb' IS_TEMPLATE = TRUE TEMPLATE='template0' ENCODING='UTF8' LC_COLLATE='C' LC_CTYPE="C.utf8";`

Comment: `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` have to be the same and match the encoding.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Meaning `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` must be "C.utf8". I tried that too. But I still get the error: invalid local name: "C.utf8". 

Is it possible that C.utf8 is indeed unavailable? But my question is why did pg_collation have C.utf8. And why did SHOW LC_CTYPE only respond with en_US.UTF-8

Comment: `SHOW` just shows the current value of a configuration parameter. I don't know why you get that error. Probably Amazon weirdness. Ask them, since you cannot get at the operating system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231408/discussion-between-clmno-and-laurenz-albe).